# call Reference by string

Tags: java, reference

In my code, I have an HPContentModule:

```
@Resource(name = "HPContentModule")
private HPContentModule hpContentModule;
```

I am wondering if it is possible to get a `String` such that:

```
String myString = "hpContentModule";
```

so that I can then call `hpContentModule` using `myString`, doing something like  `myString.init();`, where `init()` is a method in `HPContentMethod`?

Or,

If I have the bean:

```
<beans:bean id="myBean" class="com.app.search.HPContent" />
```

Can I call this bean by `String` in the controller?

Comment: I suspect that depends on your DI/IOC framework. Which one are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11741450/106261

Comment: You should be able to just call whatever container is providing the resource annotation to look up the resource by name and then pass myString as the argument (if that's what you're asking for), though that would defeat the purpose of the injection.  After the value is injected you should be able to use reflection.

Comment: I'm using Spring and i'm trying to dynamically load module.

Comment: What's stopping you from getting the bean context and accessing/casting the bean based on the String? Of interest, one thing that I found recently was that you can assign `<constructor-arg ref="..." />` values dynamically. By that, I meant that you can load a resource file that supplies the name of the bean that you are interested in loading (e.g., `<constructor-arg ref="${hpContentModuleName}" />`).

Comment: I want to create web template with dynamic loading modules. Names of modules are saved in database, so i'm getting data string and loading module. Thahs why i need to load bean by String.

Comment: If you want to load different modules dynamically, then you probably don't want to use injection.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this can be done.

One of the simplest is with Spring's `ApplicationContext`.  There are [several ways](http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/spring-application-context/) you can gain access to the `ApplicationContext`.  Once you have a copy of the `ApplicationContext` you can call the `getBean()` method like so:

```
HPContentModule hpContentModule = (HPContentModule) appContext.getBean( "myBean" );
```